# kendo grid : filtering on an array object

Tags: c#, javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I want to filter on a kendo grid that it's model has list of objects.

My filter is not working on a list of Contacts:

Here's my javascript code:

```
var typeFilter;
var contactsFilter;
var datesFilter;
var ByFiler;
var zeroFilter = {
    field: "ID",
    operator: "eq",
    value: 0
};

function filterOnMultiSelectContacts(e) {

    var filters;
    for (var i = 0; i < $('#ContactsDropDownFilter').data("kendoMultiSelect").dataItems().length; i++)
    {
        filters =[
                    {
                        field: "Contacts.ContactID",
                        operator: "eq",
                        value: Number($('#ContactsDropDownFilter').data("kendoMultiSelect").dataItems()[i].ContactID)
                    },
                        zeroFilter
        ]
    }

    contactsFilter = {
        logic: "or",
        filters: filters
    };
    applyFilters();
}

function TypeChanged(e) {
    var type = $("#SelectedType").val();
    var value = Number(type);

    if (value === -1) {
        typeFilter = null;
    }
    else {
        typeFilter = {
            logic: "or",
            filters: [
                {
                    field: "Type",
                    operator: "eq",
                    value: value
                },
                zeroFilter
            ]
        };
    }
    applyFilters();
}


function applyFilters() {
    var ds = $("#Grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource;
    var filters = [];

    if (typeFilter) filters.push(typeFilter);
    if (contactsFilter) filters.push(contactsFilter);
    if (datesFilter) filters.push(datesFilter);
    ds.filter(filters);
}
```

The filter on my date and on my type is working fine because the fields (model) are not an array. On the other hand, my `filterOnMultiSelectContacts()` function is not working correctly. My guess that my mistake is this line `field: "Contacts.ContactID"`. This line is working fine by guetting the correct ContactID :

`Number($('#ContactsDropDownFilter').data("kendoMultiSelect").dataItems()[i].ContactID)`

By the way here's my razor datasource for the grid:

```
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
    .Ajax()
    .ServerOperation(false)
    .Events(e => e.Sync("SyncLogEventGrid"))
    .Model(m =>
    {
        m.Id(t => t.LogEventID);
        m.Field(u => u.CreatedByContact).DefaultValue(UserHelper.GetCurrentUserContact(Request.RequestContext));
        m.Field(u => u.CreatedBy).DefaultValue(UserHelper.GetCurrentUserContact(Request.RequestContext).ContactID);
        m.Field(u => u.Contacts).DefaultValue(new List<ContactModel>());
        m.Field(u => u.LogEventAttachments).DefaultValue(new List<LogEventAttachmentModel>());
    })
    )
```

#### EDIT

I added in my model ContactIds which contains the Ids of the contacts (not the whole object). I came up with this but it's still not working...

```
function filterOnMultiSelectContacts(e) {
    contactsFilter = null;
    var ContactIdsList = new Array();
    for (var i = 0; i < $('#LogEventContactsDropDownFilter').val().length; i++)
    {
        ContactIdsList.push(Number($('#LogEventContactsDropDownFilter').val()[i]));
    }

    var filters;
    if ($('#LogEventContactsDropDownFilter').data("kendoMultiSelect").dataItems().length > 0) {
        filters = [
                    {
                        field: "ContactIDs",
                        operator: "eq",
                        value: ContactIdsList
                    }
                    ,
                    zeroFilter
        ];
        contactsFilter = {
            logic: "or",
            filters: filters
        };
    }
    else
    {
        contactsFilter = null;
    }
    applyFilters();
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I finally make it work, here's the solution:

```
MyFunctions = {
    getIntersect: function (arr1, arr2) {
        var intersect = [];

        for (i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
            if ($.inArray(arr2[i], arr1) > -1)
                intersect.push(arr2[i]);
        }

        return intersect;
    }
}

function filterOnMultiSelectContacts(e) {
    filterBtnClicked(e, $(this));
    contactsFilter = null;

    var filters;
    if ($('#LogEventContactsDropDownFilter').data("kendoMultiSelect").dataItems().length > 0)
    {
        var ContactIdsList = new Array();
        for (var i = 0; i < $('#LogEventContactsDropDownFilter').val().length; i++) {
            ContactIdsList.push(Number($('#LogEventContactsDropDownFilter').val()[i]));
        }
        filters = [
                    {
                        field: "ContactIDs",
                        operator: function (items, filterValue) {

                            var intersect = MyFunctions.getIntersect(items, ContactIdsList);
                            if (intersect.length > 0) return true;
                            return false;
                        },
                        value: ContactIdsList
                    }
                    ,
                    zeroFilter
                ];
        contactsFilter = {
            logic: "or",
            filters: filters
        };
    }

    else
    {
        contactsFilter = null;
    }
    applyFilters();
}

function applyFilters() {
    var ds = $("#Grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource;
    var filters = [];

    if (typeFilter) filters.push(typeFilter);
    if (contactsFilter) filters.push(contactsFilter);
    if (datesFilter) filters.push(datesFilter);
    ds.filter(filters);
}
```

I needed to create a function that intersects the given array with the items of the grid's datasource.

Comment: now in 2022 filter.operator is not a function anymore :( 
https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource/configuration/filter#filteroperator